# REST C#: why is my auth. request failing but postman works

Tags: c#

I am doing a simple call to an api giving it a token:

```
var url = baseUrl + "buildings";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
string content = (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

From the debugger I know that the header looks like this:

[image]

I know for a fact that the token is correct.

Here is the same in Postman which works:

[image]

Why is postman working and c# isnt? The header should be the same.
The returned message from the server is: JWT TOKEN NOT FOUND

EDIT.

its gets more wired:
I am able to access another api endpoint (different url, same base url) with the exact code as posted and the same token. This works fine, but the base url returns TOKEN NOT FOUND, again, only not working in c#, while working from postman..?!?

Comment: Can you try ```HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <token>");```

Comment: still no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code is correct. It turns out that the URL had to end on a "/" (slash). Allthough postman did the auto generated code WITHOUT the "/", it is neccissarry in c#. Dont ask,...

Comment: You should accept your answer, so that people facing the same issue can easily check your solution

Comment: @limserhane I will... in 17 hours ;)

Comment: This has got to be the longest 17 hours in all our lives!  That being said this was the issue.  Please mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not an authorization or authentication header, it's just a header with the key "Authorization".

Change this line:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

to this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
```

You can actually see that in Postman as well, in Postman there is a tab authorization which is (most likely) empty since there are no auth-headers present in the request.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still returned JWT token not found..

Comment: The address does not redirect anything? Using redirect can cause the headers to be stripped - if you have the option to check in debug if the token is there - also you could try to test if the JWT token is actually valid using https://jwt.io

Comment: All I am getting is JWT token not found. I just validated the token, it IS correct. I am getting the token first requesting it from the same API, no issue here. Then feeding it into the next request and suddelny, NOT FOUND.

Comment: Could you try to add it without validation using TryAddWithoutValidation ?

Comment: Also: in postman, the tab auth i created with "bearer" and then the token on the right. So the tab is not empty.

Comment: i did TryAddWithoutValidation but no change.

Comment: If that's the case your code was correct - it is an authentication header, you could try to follow your request using Wireshark or Fiddler

Comment: I know, my code was working 2 weeks ago. I havnt toucht it. I also didnt touch postman, but postman works...